# typescript + arquivo de definição de tipo (.d.ts) + enumeração (enum)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estou tentando criar um arquivo de definição que utiliza um enumerador, definido em outro arquivo, e uma variável declarada (declare var) no arquivo.d.ts, mas ao referenciar este arquivo em outro de implementação, o mesmo informa que a variável não existe.

Removendo o *import* e declarando o enumerador no arquivo .d.ts a variável *vmMensagem* reconhece normalmente, porém ocorre o erro de que o enumerador não é o mesmo do arquivo type.enum.

Se da forma que eu fiz não funciona, como posso declarar um enumerador para que eu possa reutilizá-lo em vários locais do projeto?

**type.enum.ts**

```
export enum TipoMensagem {
    INFO = 0, ALERT = 1, ERROR = 2, OK = 3
}

export enum FiltroLogica {
    E = 1, OU = 2
}
```

**vm.mensagem.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

import Enums = require("app/types/type.enum");

interface Mensagem {
    tipo: Enums.TipoMensagem;
    texto: string;
}

interface MensagemVM {
    listaMensagem: KnockoutObservableArray<Mensagem>;
    ExibirMensagem(tipo: Enums.TipoMensagem, texto: string): void;
    FadeIn(elem, index, item): void;
}

declare var vmMensagem: MensagemVM;
```

**type.mensagem.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/vms/common/vm.mensagem.d.ts" />

import Enums = require("app/types/type.enum");

class Mensagem {

    tipo: Enums.TipoMensagem;
    texto: string;

    public constructor(tipo: Enums.TipoMensagem, txt: string) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.texto = txt;
    }

    //Exibe a mensagem no elemento informado
    public SetElement(htmlElem: HTMLElement): void {
        $(htmlElem).delay(5000).fadeOut(600, () => {
            if (vmMensagem.listaMensagem.length == 0)
                return;

            $(this).remove();
            vmMensagem.listaMensagem.remove(this);
        });
    }
} 

export = Mensagem;
```

Em **type.mensagem.ts** na função *public SetElement(htmlElem: HTMLElement): void* ocorre o erro de compilação *Could not find symbol 'vmMensagem'.*

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver meu problema.

Removi o arquivo **type.enum.ts** e criei outro de definição (*enum.d.ts*) contendo os enumeradores, referenciando-o nos arquivos necessários, porquanto não é necessário importar o arquivo contendo os enumeradores no qual o .js gerado já tem os valores aplicados diretamente, servindo apenas como referência no desenvolvimento.

**enum.d.ts**

```
declare module Enums {
    enum TipoMensagem {
        INFO = 0, ALERT = 1, ERROR = 2, OK = 3
    }

    enum FiltroLogica {
        E = 1, OU = 2
    }
}
```